# Hyperlinking to same document with generate-id()

Tags: xml, xslt, dom

I'm trying to create links to the same document with my XML and XSLT. I'm trying to use generate-id() to create an index then anchors for the respective items.

problem is, the element name is not the same in the XML but i wish to link to it.

for example

XML:

```
  <testresults>
      <test testname="ComparisonResult">
        <step stepname="Step1">
          <result>true</result>
        </step>
        <step stepname="Step2" >
          <result>true</result>
        </step>
      </test>
      <step stepname="results" stepresult="true">
        <drilldown>
          <taskresults>
            <testResults>
              <test testname="ComparisonResult_Step1">

              </test>
              <test testname="ComparisonResult_Step2">

              </test>
            </testResults>
          </taskresults>
        </drilldown>
      </step>

    </testresults>
```

XSLT:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <body>
            <font face="Arial" size="2">

            <h4>Steps</h4>


      <table border="1" bordercolor="#000000">
                  <tr bgcolor="#dccdc">
                    <th align="center">Task</th>
                  </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="testresults/test/step">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">                  
                        <a href="#{generate-id(@stepname)}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@stepname" />
                        </a>                    
                      </td>                   

                    </tr>       
                    </xsl:for-each>             
                    </table>

              <h2>Test Results</h2>  

                  <xsl:for-each select="testresults/step/drilldown/taskresults/testResults/test">

                <h3>
                <a name="{generate-id(@testname)}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@testname" />
                  </a>
                </h3>

                </xsl:for-each>

                </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please ignore any mistakes, this is a quick mockup but you should get an idea of what im trying to do. I can't get it to link to the corresponding item. I.e Step1 to ComparisonResult_Step1.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly I don't see why you need generate-id, as long as those names are unique then doing e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="testresults/test/step">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">                  
                        <a href="#{concat(parent::test/@testname, '_', @stepname)}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@stepname" />
                        </a>                    
                      </td>                   

                    </tr>       
                    </xsl:for-each>             
                    </table>

              <h2>Test Results</h2>  

                  <xsl:for-each select="testresults/step/drilldown/taskresults/testResults/test">

                <h3>
                <a name="{@testname}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@testname" />
                  </a>
                </h3>

                </xsl:for-each>
```

should suffice.

If you want to use generate-id then it only makes sense if you apply it to the same node.

[edit] If you want to use generate-id then add `<xsl:key name="k1" match="testresults/step/drilldown/taskresults/testResults/test" use="@testname"/>` as a child of the xsl:stylesheet element, then change your code to e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="testresults/test/step">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">                  
                        <a href="#{generate-id(key('k1', concat(parent::test/@testname, '_', @stepname)))}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@stepname" />
                        </a>                    
                      </td>                   

                    </tr>       
                    </xsl:for-each>             
                    </table>

              <h2>Test Results</h2>  

                  <xsl:for-each select="testresults/step/drilldown/taskresults/testResults/test">

                <h3>
                <a name="{generate-id()}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@testname" />
                  </a>
                </h3>

                </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that relies on the relative position of each of the steps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <font face="Arial" size="2">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </font>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="testresults/test">
        <h4>Steps</h4>
        <table border="1" bordercolor="#000000">
            <tr bgcolor="#dccdc">
                <th align="center">Task</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- links -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="step" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="testresults/test/step">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                <a
                    href="#{generate-id(../../step/drilldown/taskresults
                                /testResults/test[position()=$pos])}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@stepname" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="drilldown/taskresults/testResults">
        <h2>Test Results</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="test" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="drilldown/taskresults/testResults/test">
        <h3>
            <a name="{generate-id(.)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@testname" />
            </a>
        </h3>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the provided input:

```
<testresults>
    <test testname="ComparisonResult">
        <step stepname="Step1">
            <result>true</result>
        </step>
        <step stepname="Step2">
            <result>true</result>
        </step>
    </test>
    <step stepname="results" stepresult="true">
        <drilldown>
            <taskresults>
                <testResults>
                    <test testname="ComparisonResult_Step1"></test>
                    <test testname="ComparisonResult_Step2"></test>
                </testResults>
            </taskresults>
        </drilldown>
    </step>
</testresults>
```

Produces:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <font face="Arial" size="2">
            <h4>Steps</h4>
            <table border="1" bordercolor="#000000">
                <tr bgcolor="#dccdc">
                    <th align="center">Task</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                        <a href="#d1e26">Step1</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#F2F5A9">
                        <a href="#d1e29">Step2</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <h2>Test Results</h2>
            <h3><a name="d1e26">ComparisonResult_Step1</a></h3>
            <h3><a name="d1e29">ComparisonResult_Step2</a></h3>
        </font>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** This solution does not use `for-each` in a monolithic template. Instead, it relies on multiple templates to modularize the handling of each section of the input.